# Can I use Playstation controller button icons in my game?

Tags: legal, licensing, controllers

I'm currently working on a game that will be released on PC with controller support, and I'm trying to find a way on how to best represent controller icons within the game.

[image]

I'm assuming I can't simply use Playstation or Xbox controller icons in my game without having some form of license first (right?).

So how would it be best to convey something like 'Press X to interact' in a PC game for controllers?

Comment: I'm really hoping that someone with legal knowledge or direct experience could provide a better answer; However, the best idea I can come up with is to show a diamond of four buttons(common to all current controllers), with no labelling, and highlight one of them. I think Microsoft may have some document approving the use of 360 buttons, so at least that side would be easier to handle.

Comment: Considering [motioninjoy driver](http://www.motioninjoy.com/) is a hack (unlike the Microsoft-endorsed [XBox 360 controller driver](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads)) and the ps3 controller is of course patented, I'd say steer clear of this, and use XBox 360 controller button labels instead.

Comment: Yea, I decided I'm gonna go for the XBox controller ones instead of the PS3 ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While the letter X is not copy protected, the specific cross used on the controller, along with the other shapes: [image], [are trademarked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Controller). Using your own art to represent the buttons (as in your example image), should be OK under [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use_%28U.S._trademark_law%29), specifically [nominative fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_use). Where the qualifications for nominative fair use are one of the following situations:

> - The product or service cannot be readily identified without using the
>     trademark (e.g. trademark is descriptive of a person, place, or
>     product attribute).
> - The user only uses as much of the mark as is
>     necessary for the identification (e.g. the words but not the font or
>     symbol).
> - The user does nothing to suggest sponsorship or endorsement
>     by the trademark holder. This applies even if the nominative use is
>     commercial, and the same test applies for metatags.

In this case, you're not trying to use the symbols as your own, but instead are directly referring to Sony's trademarked buttons, which likely falls under the first category.

If you're unsure, talk to a lawyer. If you're taking advice from someone on the internet, talk to a lawyer.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer @Byte56, it was exactly what I was looking for.