# Is it legit to use Custom Controller Buttons for PC Games in Unity?

Tags: controllers, xbox-controller

Not sure if this is off topic, but I have a problem. I'm making buttons for my own controller in my Game. For example, the attached images will appear to indicate the player to press the A or B Buttons. The image resembles Xbox Controller Buttons. So, is it legit to use them as Buttons of my own Custom Controller?[image: A Button Icon][image]

Comment: I think this is more of a law question than a question regarding game development. And this it's better asked in the Law Stack Exchange

Comment: I think that as long as you don't "*steal*" the images from someone without permission and you don't include xbox's logo anywhere, you should be totally fine. again, i'm not a layer or law expert, so you might want to ask on LawSE.

Comment: Sure one would say that they remind them of XboX's buttons, but the letters are not the same (in XboX A is green and X is blue, while B is red), and I can't picture a company having the copyright of a "green button with letter". Having said that, I'm not a lawyer, but if you are indeed not trying to copy another company's work, you can just make your button's original, and that should be enough.

Comment: Related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61181/can-i-use-playstation-controller-button-icons-in-my-game - although one might take the view that the PlayStation's buttons are more easily trademarked than the letters A and B.  But nonetheless opinion is not what matters here, trademark law is, and the closing sentences of the answer to the question I've linked remain relevant: "If you're unsure, talk to a lawyer. If you're taking advice from someone on the internet, talk to a lawyer."

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. I’ll just take this question to the law stack exchange.

Comment: I suggest you read carefully their help center before posting there.

Comment: Also note that even law.stackexchange is still just "someone on the internet"; you have basically got **no way whatsoever** to confirm the credentials of any random Joe-on-the-internet who says either "yes" or "no" to such a question.  So if your question is "will I get my ass sued off me if I do this" you really need professional, accredited and competent legal advice; random and otherwise unknown people on the internet don't cut it.

Answer (score 3):

There are official Xbox 360 button and controller images available under the [Microsoft Permissive License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL). They were originally released for use by *XNA Game Studio* titles, but you are free to use them by the license without *XNA Game Studio*.

You can find the original downloads still available from a XNA Game Studio archive site:

[Xbox Common Controller Images](https://github.com/SimonDarksideJ/XNAGameStudio/wiki/Xbox-360-Controller-Button-Images)

[Xbox Common Controller Button images](https://github.com/SimonDarksideJ/XNAGameStudio/wiki/Xbox-360-Controller-Images)

> I have the button artwork arranged in a sprite sheet you can use as well from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/images/xboxControllerSpriteFont.png) under the [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)--Microsoft legal recommends we release content under MIT instead of MS-PL these days.

[image: Xbox 360 buttons]

> At the moment, there's no Xbox One generation controller artwork available under a public license.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from legal issues, the colors you chose are just plain confusing. On a first party controller (which most people use) A is green, B is red, X is blue and Y is yellow. These make sense based on the most common uses for these. A is generally used for confirming actions, B is for "back" or "no", etc.

Making the button colors differ from what's in front of you is the same as if I put basic quiz questions in front of you. What's the color of the text on this image?
[image]